# Logistic Regression: Behavior of Independent Variable Plots

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm doing a study where I am using a logitisc regression to estimate the probability that an account will prepay their monthly scheduled bill. Data description includes: total observations = 40000, total number of observations that prepay (1) = 5250, total number of observations don't prepay (0) = 34750.

Right now, my explanatory variables include: Account Age and Incentive to Prepay. Both variables are continuous and measured quantitatively. When I plot Incentive and Account Age against the dependent variable, which is prepaid = 1 and no prepay = 0, I get these interesting graphs. I'm not necessarily sure how I should interpret these graphs. My initial thought, is that I need to change the functional form to quadratic/cubic for the graph with incentive.

I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on the behavior of these graphs. Thanks a lot!

[image: Incentive Plot]

[image: Age Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right kind of visualization that should be done before you embark on your logistic regression endeavors.

It suggests to me that a logistic regression with a spline term could be appropriate for these data. Generally statisticians will consider splines to be more reliable than polynomial models. Take a look at the mgcv package in R, and think about trying out

```
fit <- gam(level ~ s(age, incentive), data = your_data, 
           family = binomial())
```

as a model. The `gam` function from `mgcv` will fit a logistic regression model with penalized thin plate splines.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions its a huge help!